# Expected number of parallel tosses, where each coin gets heads at least once, of N unfair coins

Tags: probability, expectation

A common expectation question is to ask "What is the expected number of tosses to get heads with an unfair coin?" This problem can be solved using the recursive equation E = p*1+(1-p)*(E+1), resulting in the solution of E=1/p, where p is the probability of getting heads.

If the question is changed to "What is the expected number of parallel tosses, where each coin gets heads at least once, with N unfair coins assuming each coin has equal probability?," does the solution stay as E=1/p, because each coin is independent or is the solution more complicated? If the solution is more complicated, how is it solved?

Comment: Does that mean if I'm tossing five coins, I get one to flip heads after lets 6 tries and rest haven't yet. Do I just flip 4 coins now or still flip that already got heads

Comment: also is each unfair coin have same probability of getting heads

Comment: Comment 1) The fact that the first coin received heads means that the 1st coin is successful. For the remaining 4 coins, whether or not the 1st coin is flipped again shouldn't matter. Comment 2) yes, each coin has the same probability of getting heads.

Comment: It seems to me that each experiment now is tossing two coins.  The probability that _at least_ one is heads is the compliment to the probability that they are _both_ tails (the negation): $1 - \frac{1}{2^2} = \frac{3}{4}$.  So now the expected number of trials is $\frac{1}{p} = \frac{4}{3} = 1 + \frac{1}{3}$ (instead of $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}} = 2$).

Comment: This is incorrect, since your expected number of tosses of using 2 coins would be fewer than a single coin. The expected number of parallel tosses for N coins, where each coin got heads at least once, should be at least the number of tosses for a single coin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recurrence can be written as:

\begin{align*}
   E_n& = \dfrac{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}p^{n-k}q^{k}E_k}{1 - q^n} \\ E_1 &= \frac{1}{p} \\   
\end{align*}
where $p$ is the probability of getting head.

Hence, when $p=1/2$, we find that $E_5 = 2470/651 \approx 3.79416282642$

Comment: I like it, and agrees with simulations.

Comment: Did you mean for $E_{1}=\frac{1}{p}$ and is $q=(1-p)$

Comment: @user159813 : Thanks. I was trying an absorbing markov chain and ended up with this. Ah yes, I wrote that keeping p=1/2 in mind, will update.

Comment: It appears that a factor of ${n \choose k}$ is missing in the numerator.

Comment: @saulspatz Shouldn´t you (we) make an edit. I don´t think that gar will answer in any time soon. Her/his latest answer was in january.

Comment: @callculus I hate to just change an answer, especially one that's been accepted. I don't know what the protocol is.  In any event, let's wait a day or so and see if gar edits it.

Comment: @saulspatz On the other hand, especially if it is accepted isn´t it an additional reason to improve the answer?

Comment: @callculus Like I said, I don't know what the protocol is.  Feel free to edit it yourself, if you think that's appropriate.

Comment: @gar In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2892447/expected-number-of-parallel-tosses-of-n-unfair-coins-until-all-coins-landed-he) saulpatz and Jared Goguen think that you have omitted the binomial coefficient, $\binom{n}{k}$. I´ve made an edit.

Comment: @callculus & saulspatz Ah, a typo caught after 4 years! Thanks for fixing! Wish I get more time to do math..

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for spotting the typo

Comment: @gar I didn´t expect that your reply comes so fast since your last post was in January.

Comment: @gar Glad to help.

Comment: @callculus yeah, but I usually visit once or twice a week

Answer (score 1):

For N coins, we notice each coin is an independent random variable lets say $X_{i}$ for $i=1,...,N$. Now since we are trying to count how many tosses till get heads each $X_{i}\sim Geometric(p)$ (where p is probability of getting heads). Thus in order the random variable that describes how many tosses until all N coins get heads is $W=max \left\{X_{1},...,X_{N}\right\}$ where this distribution is derived as follows
$$F_{W}(w)=P(W\leq w)=P(max \left\{X_{1},...,X_{N}\right\}\leq w)=\prod_{i=1}^{N}P(X_{i}\leq w)=\left(F_{X}(w)\right)^{N}$$
thus pdf is 
$$f_{w}(w)=\frac{\delta}{\delta w}\left(F_{X}(w)\right)^{N}=N\left(F_{X}(w)\right)^{N-1}f_{X}(w)=N(1-(1-p)^{w+1})^{N-1}(1-p)^{w}p$$
Thus expected value would be 
$$\sum_{w=0}^{\infty}wN(1-(1-p)^{w+1})^{N-1}(1-p)^{w}p$$
which I couldn't derive explicitly so I did a simulation instead with $N=5$ and $p=\frac{1}{2}$ where R code is as follows

> ```
> meanToss=function(numToss)
>
> {
>
> arr=NULL
> ```
>
> for(i in 1:1000)
>
> ```
> {
>
>    coins=rep(0,numToss)
>
>    trials=rep(0,numToss)
>
>    while(sum(coins)!=length(coins))
> ```
>
> {
>
> ```
>   for(j in 1:numToss)
>
>   {
>
>       if(coins[j]==0)
>
>       {
>
>           flip=sample(c(0,1),1)
>
>           coins[j]=flip
>
>           trials[j]=trials[j]+1
>
>       }
>
>   }
>
> }
>
>    arr[i]=max(trials)
>
> }
>
> return(mean(arr))
>
> }
> ```

I got that you would expect about 3.77 trials to have all get heads
Below is graph of expected value over different N

[image]

Comment: This is an article I found about expected value of maximum of iid geometric(p) rvs http://mikespivey.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/expectedmaxgeometric/

Comment: Also the intuition Im starting to get from these graphs and this article is that. As you have more parallel tosses of coin you allow more of a chance for any given repetition of flips till heads of getting a coin that happens to get the very low individual probability of not getting heads for many upon many flips, but this begins to level off after a while