# Expected number of parallel tosses of $N$ unfair coins until all coins landed head at least once

Tags: probability, expectation, markov-chains

I am trying to understand [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/862972/103895), but it doesn't work when I plug in the numbers. Given the recurrence relation

\begin{align*}
  E_n &= \dfrac{\displaystyle 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}q^kp^{n-k}E_{k}}{1-q^n} \\
  E_1 &= \frac{1}{p}
\end{align*}

and assuming $p = q = 1/2$, we can compute $E_5$ as:

\begin{align}
E_1 &= 2\\
E_2 &= \frac{1 + (1/2)(1/2)2}{1-(1/4)} = \frac{6}{3} = 2\\
E_3 &= \frac{1 + (1/2)(1/4)2 + (1/4)(1/2)2}{1-(1/8)} = \frac{12}{7} \approx 1.714\\
E_4 &= \frac{1 + (1/2)(1/8)2 + (1/4)(1/4)2 + (1/8)(1/2)(12/7)}{1-(1/16)} = \frac{152}{105} \approx 1.448\\
E_5 &= \frac{1 + (1/2)(1/16)2 + (1/4)(1/8)2 + (1/8)(1/4)(12/7) + (1/16)(1/2)(152/105)}{1-(1/32)} = \frac{4112}{3255} \approx 1.263,
\end{align}

which does not match the author's answer of $E_5 = 2470/651 \approx 3.79416282642$.

I have no experience with absorbing Markov chains so I have no idea where the mistake is.  Am I doing something wrong or is the answer wrong?

(Apologies if this is not the right place.  I would have posted this as a comment to the answer, but my reputation is not high enough to do that...)

Comment: The author's actual expected value of 3.794 is consistent with simulations regardless of whether that value is consistent with their recurrence relation.

Comment: Note that $E_2 = \frac{8}{3}$ is a correct value in the series. Similarly, $E_3 = \frac{22}{7}$.

Comment: There must be something wrong with the formula.  How can the expected number of tosses decrease as the number of coins increases?

Comment: I think the recurrence relation should be $$E_n=1+\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}p^{n-k}q^kE_k$$ for $n>0$

Comment: @saulspatz There is something incorrect in that - $E_n$ occurs on the RHS.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Yes, but you can solve for $E_n$.  It looks to me like that what was done in the original answer, by the author left out the binomial coefficients.

Comment: Gotcha, that produces $$ E_n = \frac{1+\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}p^{n-k}q^{k}E_k}{1 - q^n} $$

Comment: Note the the original post has been corrected.  It was just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recurrence relation given by @saulspatz in the comments is correct. Solved for $E_n$, it is:

$$ E_n = \dfrac{1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}p^{n-k}q^{k}E_k}{1 - q^n} $$

with $ E_1 = \frac{1}{p} $. This form correctly predicts $ E_2 = \frac{8}{3} $ and $ E_3 = \frac{22}{7} $, as well as $ E_5 = \frac{2470}{651}$.

Comment: The starting index k=0 actually works if we interpret $k$ in $E_k$ as the number of coins that still need to be flipped to heads. Then trivially $E_0=0$ and $E_1=1/p$ follows from recurrence relation.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the probability of needing $m$ parallel rolls is
given by

$$\mathrm{P}[T=m] = \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}
(1-q^{m-1})^{n-k} q^{(m-1)k} (1-q)^k.$$

Here we choose the $k$ coins that have not landed a head yet and which
see  their  first  head  on  the  $m$th roll.   Check  if  this  is  a
probability distribution:

$$\sum_{m\ge 1} \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}
(1-q^{m-1})^{n-k} q^{(m-1)k} (1-q)^k
\\ = \sum_{m\ge 1}
\left(-(1-q^{m-1})^n +
(q^{m-1}(1-q) + 1 - q^{m-1})^n\right)
\\ = \sum_{m\ge 1}
\left(-(1-q^{m-1})^n + (1 - q^m)^n\right).$$

The partial sums  to an upper limit of $m'$  are $(1-q^{m'})^n$ so the
series converges to  a value of one, confirming the  sanity check.  We
then have for the expectation

$$\sum_{m=1}^{m'} m
\left(-(1-q^{m-1})^n + (1 - q^m)^n\right)
\\ = - \sum_{m=0}^{m'-1} (m+1) (1-q^{m})^n
+ \sum_{m=1}^{m'} m (1 - q^m)^n
\\ = m'(1-q^{m'})^n
- \sum_{m=0}^{m'-1} (1-q^{m})^n.$$

The  sum  is   (the  term  for  $m=0$  is  zero   and  simplifies  the
computation):

$$\sum_{m=0}^{m'-1} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k q^{km}
\\ = m' + \sum_{m=0}^{m'-1} \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k q^{km}
= m' + \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k
\sum_{m=0}^{m'-1} q^{km}
\\ = m' + \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k
\frac{1-q^{km'}}{1-q^k}.$$

Computing the limit we thus have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\mathrm{E}[T] =
 \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^{k+1}
\frac{1}{1-q^k}.}$$

This yields for a fair coin the sequence

$$2,8/3,{\frac {22}{7}},{\frac {368}{105}},
{\frac {2470}{651}},{\frac {7880}{1953}},
{\frac {150266}{35433}},\;\ldots$$

and  for a  coin  that  lands heads  with  probability  $3/4$ so  that
$q=1/4:$

$$3/2,{\frac {15}{8}},{\frac {225}{104}},{\frac {2487}{1040}},
{\frac {64839}{25168}},{\frac {36999}{13552}},
{\frac {78709677}{27508624}},\;\ldots$$

These values match the data from the recurrence.

**Addendum,  next day.** We  may prove  the closed form  using the
recurrence and strong  induction. For $n=1$ we get  $1/(1-q)$ which is
correct. In the induction step we find

$$\frac{1}{1-q^n} +
\frac{1}{1-q^n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} {n\choose k} p^{n-k} q^k
\sum_{\ell = 1}^k {k\choose \ell} (-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{1}{1-q^\ell}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-q^n} +
\frac{1}{1-q^n}
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-1} (-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{1}{1-q^\ell}
\sum_{k=\ell}^{n-1} {n\choose k} p^{n-k} q^k {k\choose \ell}.$$

Working with the sum we observe that

$${n\choose k} {k\choose \ell} =
\frac{n!}{(n-k)! \times \ell! \times (k-\ell)!}
= {n\choose \ell} {n-\ell\choose n-k}$$

and we obtain

$$\frac{1}{1-q^n}
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-1} {n\choose \ell}
(-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{1}{1-q^\ell}
\sum_{k=\ell}^{n-1} {n-\ell\choose n-k} p^{n-k} q^k
\\ = \frac{1}{1-q^n}
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-1} {n\choose \ell}
(-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{1}{1-q^\ell}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-\ell-1} {n-\ell\choose n-k-\ell}
p^{n-k-\ell} q^{k+\ell}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-q^n}
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-1} {n\choose \ell}
(-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{q^\ell}{1-q^\ell}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-\ell-1} {n-\ell\choose k}
p^{n-\ell-k} q^{k}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-q^n}
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-1} {n\choose \ell}
(-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{q^\ell}{1-q^\ell}
((p+q)^{n-\ell}  - q^{n-\ell})
\\ = \frac{1}{1-q^n}
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-1} {n\choose \ell}
(-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{q^\ell-1+1-q^n}{1-q^\ell}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-q^n}
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-1} {n\choose \ell} (-1)^{\ell}
+ \frac{1}{1-q^n}
\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-1} {n\choose \ell}
(-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{1-q^n}{1-q^\ell}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-q^n}
(0-1-(-1)^n)
+ \sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-1} {n\choose \ell}
(-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{1}{1-q^\ell}.$$

We now restore the term in front that did not participate
to find

$$\frac{1}{1-q^n} + \frac{1}{1-q^n}
(-1+(-1)^{n+1})
+ \sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-1} {n\choose \ell}
(-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{1}{1-q^\ell}
\\ = \sum_{\ell = 1}^{n} {n\choose \ell}
(-1)^{\ell+1} \frac{1}{1-q^\ell}.$$

This concludes the proof.

Comment: I really like the closed form, but to be completely honest most of your answer went a bit over my head.  The recurrence relation is good enough for the purposes of what I'm trying to compute (and answers my question more specifically), so I'll keep the other answer as the accepted one.  Hopefully I'll have some time soon to try and really sit down to understand your answer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. It is an interesting problem and it was fun working on it.